# Stata - wbopendata r(601) error

Tags: runtime-error, stata, filenotfoundexception, temporary-files

i've recently installed `wbopendata` in `stata 12.0`.

when i try to run the comand

```
wbopendata, indicator(SH.STA.OWGH.ZS; SH.STA.STNT.ZS; SH.STA.MALN.ZS; SH.STA.WAST.ZS; SN.ITK.DPTH;  SH.STA.BRTW.ZS; SH.STA.BFED.ZS;NY.GDP.PCAP.CD; NY.GDP.MKTP.CD; GDPPCKD) long clear
```

this error apears:

```
file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ST_0c000002.tmp not found r(601);
```

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: This works for me: `wbopendata, indicator(SH.STA.OWGH.ZS; SH.STA.STNT.ZS) long clear`. How about for you?

Comment: Thank's for your answer Roberto. It doesn't work. The same error appears:

file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ST_0c000002.tmp not found

Comment: Try updating to Stata 12.1 and report back your version of `wbopendata` using `which`.

Answer (score 0):

I also have an error r(601) with wbopendata and fix it by updating to latest Stata (13).